# Add new Row in List and

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to create a new list  in SharePoint 2010. when I enter new row in list , it also add new row in my custom database also.

Can anyone give me idea how can I write code or design my SharePoint Site?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You need a ItemAdded event which will add entry to your database table when someone will add a item this event or code will trigger and will save data using SQL insert query into database, but I recommend you using Stored procudure.

[Using Event Receivers in SharePoint Foundation 2010 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749858%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, Raja Please can you give me url of example

Comment: check this blogpost http://sharepointbulletin.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/adding-details-to-database-table-using.html